# two taps to full and two tap the screen to return to normal

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to have two taps to make it full screen and two taps to return to regular. However, the two GestureRecognizers are conflicting and are both getting called resulting in the screen not changing. How do I fix that?

Here is my code:

```
-(void) tap2Full {    

    //Teste apartir daqui "TAP"
    UITapGestureRecognizer *fullScreen = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fullScreen)];
    fullScreen.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *screenOut = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenOut)];
    screenOut.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

    // stops tapOnce from overriding tapTwice
    [fullScreen requireGestureRecognizerToFail:screenOut];

    fullScreen.delegate = self;
    screenOut.delegate = self;

    [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:fullScreen];
    [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:screenOut];

}

- (void)fullScreen {
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = -1;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.webView];
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.webView.layer.zPosition = 9;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}

- (void)screenOut {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = 1;
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 113, 320, 455);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed in your code. Please it hope this is work for you.

```
//Global BOOL flag

BOOL isTapOnScreen;

-(void) tap2Full {    

    isTapOnScreen = TRUE;
    //Teste apartir daqui "TAP"
    UITapGestureRecognizer *fullScreen = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fullScreen)];
    fullScreen.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    fullScreen.delegate = self;

   [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:fullScreen];
}

- (void)fullScreen {
    if(isTapOnScreen == FALSE) {

          self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = 1;
          self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 113, 320, 455);
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
          isTapOnScreen = TRUE;
    }
    else {
         self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = -1;
         [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.webView];
         self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width,    self.view.frame.size.height);
         self.webView.layer.zPosition = 9;
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
         isTapOnScreen = FALSE;
   }
}
```

Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to this. The first is using only one gesture, and the second is where you will remove and re add them as you need them.

> With this method you are using only one gestureRecognizer:

```
@implementation YourController {
    BOOL isFullScreen;
}

-(void) tap2Full {    

    isFullScreen = FALSE;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *toggleScreen = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleScreen)];
    toggleScreen.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    toggleScreen.delegate = self;

   [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:fullScreen];
}

- (void) toggleScreen {
    if(isFullScreen) {
          self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = 1;
          self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 113, 320, 455);
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
          isFullScreen = FALSE;
    } else {
         self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = -1;
         [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.webView];
         self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width,    self.view.frame.size.height);
         self.webView.layer.zPosition = 9;
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
         isFullScreen = TRUE;
   }
}
```

> With this method of fixing your issue you will be removing the
>   gestureRecognizers when you do not need them and re-add them when you
>   do.

What you need to do is add the gestures here:

```
@implementation YourController {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *fullScreen;    
    UITapGestureRecognizer *screenOut;
}
```

And then change `tap2F`:

```
    fullScreen = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fullScreen)];
    fullScreen.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

    screenOut = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenOut)];
    screenOut.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
```

And then modify `fullScreen`:

```
- (void)fullScreen {
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = -1;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.webView];
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.webView.layer.zPosition = 9;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    [self.webView removeGestureRecognizer: fullScreen];
    for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in self.webView.gestureRecognizers) {
            if (![recognizer isEqual: screenOut]) {
            [self.webView addGestureRecognizer: screenOut];
            }
    }
}
```

And change `screenOut`:

```
- (void)screenOut {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = 1;
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 113, 320, 455);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

    [self.webView removeGestureRecognizer: screenOut];

    for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in self.webView.gestureRecognizers) {
        if (![recognizer isEqual: fullScreen]) {
        [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:fullScreen];
        }
    }
}
```